# Django: DB relations - one user many other objects

Tags: python, django, database, database-relations

Is there a way to tie many objects one user from native User model? I've been reading around it, but I still don't quite understand whether I need to extend User model(I wouldn't, if not necessary), and whether that would be onetomany or manytoone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the objects point at the UserModel instead of having the UserModel pointing at other objects. 
If you do it that way, then you don't need to extend the default UserModel.

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(user)
```